# how properly save data to MongoDb throw Spring-data in no-blocking stack using CompletableFuture

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, completable-future

The question could be summarized: how properly save data to MongoDb throw Spring-data in no-blocking stack using CompletableFuture (i.e. Spring Webflux + reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository + java.util.concurrent)?

I have struglled for the last three days studing and searcing around and reading several tutorials in order to find a recommended way or at least a "north path" to persist data when someone wants to use CompletableFuture for that. I could reach the code bellow succesfully working but I am not sure if I am doing some weird stuff.

Basically, I want to use CompletableFuture because I want to chain futures. Let say, save firstly in MongoDb and if well-done then "thenAcceptAsync" and finally "thenCombine" them.

Well, ReactiveCrudRepository.save returns Mono<> and I must subscribe in order to effectivelly save it. Additionally Mono<>.subscribe() returns dispose whic I understand I can use to cancel it let's say if the thread takes too long because MongoDb is out for instance or any other exception. SO far so good.

What is unclear to me is if I am not messing up the idea of using using saving the data which blocks in assyncronous method. Since my puporse is leave to "future" resolution am I am blocking during the save method bellow and completely losing the benefitis of saving in different thread and get a future result?

Code saving properly to MongoDb but not clear to me if it is really "no-blocking" approach. Note that completableFuture.get() is commented since I don't need it in onder to effectively save my data

```
@Async("taskExecutor")
public void transferirDisposableReturnedSupplyAsync(Extrato e) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletableFuture<Disposable> completableFuture = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> extratoRepository.save(e).subscribe());

    //completableFuture.get(); unnecessary since subscribe() above already saved it
}
```

In case it is relevant:
Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import com.noblockingcase.demo.model.Extrato;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

public interface ExtratoRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Extrato, String> {
    @Query("{ id: { $exists: true }}")
    Flux<Extrato> retrieveAllExtratosPaged(final Pageable page);
}
```

AsyncConfiguration:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

// The @EnableAsync annotation enables Spring’s ability to run @Async methods in a background thread pool. 
// The bean taskExecutor helps to customize the thread executor such as configuring number of threads for an application, queue limit size and so on. 
// Spring will specifically look for this bean when the server is started. 
// If this bean is not defined, Spring will create SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor by default.

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncConfiguration.class);

    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        LOGGER.debug("Creating Async Task Executor");
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("ExtratoThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

*** added

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Extrato } from './extrato';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SseService {
  extratos: Extrato[] = [];
  constructor(private _zone: NgZone) { }

  getServerSentEvent(url: string): Observable<any> {
    this.extratos = [];
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      const eventSource = this.getEventSource(url);
      eventSource.onmessage = event => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
          let json = JSON.parse(event.data);
          this.extratos.push(new Extrato(json['id'], json['description'], json['value'], json['status']));
          observer.next(this.extratos);
        });
      };
      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      }

    });
  }
  private getEventSource(url: string): EventSource {
    return new EventSource(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not finding any answers, because a flux and mono are wrapped completable futures. You don't need the completable future, at all. Remove the completable future completlyYou chain on actions to the returned mono `extratoRepository.save(e).flatMap(result -> { // do something with the result }).subscribe()`.

You should read up what the basics of reactive programming is. Start with the excellent Reactor 3 documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/ and go through their examples.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf, do you see any diference between returning a CompletableFuture or a Flux to a client? I mean, imagine any Server Sent Event Observer you are familiar with (eg.RxJs) calling a Rest EndPoint running on No-blocking server (Let's say a popular Netty easily started by a SpringBoot with org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux). Since a Flux is a wrapped completable future I would not expect significant differences, right? I added above my Angular/RxJs. Note I am really trying a real full reactive stack.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf maybe you can write you next comment as answer so I can pick up it. Basically, you have already answer my question by commenting above